# Java: how do I find out how private variable got populated with values?

Tags: java

TLDR: servlet calls getResponse and I'm trying to find out where a variable got its values.

---

so I have the piece of code below:

```
protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

private Map<String, ApiEndpoint> apiConfigMap = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void addConfig(String configKey, ApiEndpoint apiEndpoint) {
    if(apiEndpoint != null) apiConfigMap.put(configKey, apiEndpoint);
    logger.info("ApiConfigurationImpl: updated apiConfigMap:{}",apiConfigMap);
}

@Override
public void getResponse(String param1, String param2) throws IOException {
    logger.info("im inside getResponse);

    //do stuff here
}
```

my servlet function is calling getResponse and by the time I get to  logger.info inside getResponse, the variable "apiConfigMap" already has been populated (length=19).

Any ideas how apiConfigMap could've been populated?

**Things I checked**

- The code I listed above is the only place in the class where apiConfigMap is assigned a value
- addConfig function is the only place where apiConfigMap.put exists
- I placed a breakpoint to the logger.info inside addConfig function. The execution never stopped there.
- There are other functions in the class that uses its own local HashMap variables. Just to be safe, I placed a breakpoint on the first line of each of these functions. The execution did not stop on these breakpoints as well.

Comment: The private *variable* got populated here: `apiConfigMap = new HashMap<>()`. The *object* to which it *refers* got populated by any code that succeeded in getting a reference to it.

Comment: You may need to include the whole class - there may be something happening that you think is irrelevant that isn't.  A few things to consider:  1. the Map may be perturbed outside of this class if you pass a reference to this Map to another class; 2. consider making the Map reference final to prevent unexpected replacement; 3. create a conditional breakpoint on apiConfigMap.put(..).

Comment: Instance variables load with their default values if nothing is assigned or load with the assigned value once an object is created to the class which encapsulates them. So `apiConfigMap = new HashMap<>();` will already create an object of `HashMap` once the `getResponse` method is called. The thing I don't understand is `length=19`, the map has a default initial capacity of 16.

Comment: `HashMap`s don't have lengths, they have sizes. So what exactly do you mean by `length=19`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your use of `HashMap` is prone to concurrency issues since it is not thread safe.

Replace the initialization of `apiConfigMap` with a custom map implementation (possibly by deriving from `HashMap`). Create a conditional breakpoint in all of the map methods where your custom map implementation modifies it's state and check in the condition that the instance affected is one of your custom map implementation.

Then run your application with a debugger attached and check where the debugger hits the breakpoints. Using conditional breakpoints may slow down your application. So this may take longer than usual for your application to reach a point where it started up or does something.